# Invalid credentials when trying to authenticate with password in Realm

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm trying to authenticate a user with password like this:

```
let syncCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: email, password: password, register: true)

SyncUser.logIn(with: syncCredentials, server: Constants.Realm.Server) { (realmUser, error) in
    guard let realmUser = realmUser else {
        DDLogError("\(error)")

        return
    }

    DDLogInfo("realmUser: \(realmUser)")
}
```

but it prints out this error:

> Optional(Error Domain=io.realm.sync Code=611 "The provided credentials are invalid." UserInfo={statusCode=400, NSLocalizedDescription=The provided credentials are invalid.})

The `Server` constant is correct, as I can successfully connect to the Realm Object Server using Facebook credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this error if you register the user that already exists, so specify `register: false` if the user is already registered.

Comment: I thought it threw the error for the first call too, but it looks like it worked the first time. I'll try it later, but the error message is very misleading, could it be changed? Also, what will the best practice be regarding this? Try to call it with `true` and in the error callback try again with `false`? Or is there a way to check if a user was already registered?

Comment: There is no way to check if the user already registered because it would leak the private information about existing accounts, see https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4443 for discussion.

Comment: It doesn't quite apply to my case, because I'm registering/logging the user through Firebase UI, and then trying to register it on a ROS, so I think I'll try the `false` then `true` scheme. This answer is valid nonetheless.